# How can I create a new column based on conditional statements and dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
x y
2 4
5 8
1 4
9 12
```

I have four conditions

- maxx = 3, minx = 1, maxy = 6, miny = 3. (If minx < x < maxx and miny < y < maxy, then z = apple)
- maxx = 6, minx = 4, maxy = 9, miny = 7. (If minx < x < maxx and miny < y < maxy, then z = ball)
- maxx = 2, minx = 0, maxy = 5, miny = 3. (If minx < x < maxx and miny < y < maxy, then z = pine)
- maxx = 12, minx = 7, maxy = 15, miny = 11. (If minx < x < maxx and miny < y < maxy, then z = orange)

Expected outcome:

```
x y z
2 4 apple
5 8 ball
1 4 pine 
9 12 orange
```

I have thousands of rows, and these four conditions that will fit all values.

How can I do this using the mutate function? I know how to manipulate numbers directly, but not sure how I can store a character based on conditional statements.

Comment: You can nest `ifelse`s, but it's going to get messy.

Comment: What happens when either `y` or `x` doesn't meet any condition? Or they meet different conditions?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I would like NAs there. But I don't think there are any rows in my data that don't fit into the conditions. But yeah NAs.

Comment: @alistaire I don't think ifelse's would fit here.... More equivalent to a switch statement if what I would need (I think). Maybe I'm wrong. Please feel free to give an example.

Comment: A non-dplyr solution is also fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative answer:

```
library(mosaic)
df <- mutate(df, fruit = derivedFactor(
  "apple" = (x<3 & x>1 & y<6 & y>3),
  "ball" = (x<6 & x>4 & y<9 & y>7),
  "pine" = (x<2 & x>0 & y<5 & y>3),
  "orange" = (x<12 & x>7 & y<15 & y>11),
   method ="first",
  .default = NA
))
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe the best option here is to use `dplyr::case_when`

```
df %>% mutate(z = case_when(
    x < 3  & x > 1 & y < 6  & y > 3  ~ "apple" ,
    x < 6  & x > 4 & y < 9  & y > 7  ~ "ball"  ,
    x < 2  & x > 0 & y < 5  & y > 3  ~ "pine"  ,
    x < 12 & x > 7 & y < 15 & y > 11 ~ "orange"
  )
)
```

Which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x     y z     
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     2     4 apple 
2     5     8 ball  
3     1     4 pine  
4     9    12 orange
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ifelse`, it's

```
df %>% mutate(z = ifelse(x<3 & x>1 & y<6 & y>3, 'apple', 
                         ifelse(x<6 & x>4 & y<9 & y>7, 'ball',
                                ifelse(x<2 & x>0 & y<5 & y>3, 'pine',
                                       ifelse(x<12 & x>7 & y<15 & y>11, 'orange', NA))))
)

#   x  y      z
# 1 2  4  apple
# 2 5  8   ball
# 3 1  4   pine
# 4 9 12 orange
```

Notes:

- If you have cases that match two conditions (`x = 1.5, y = 4`), this will fail.
- `dplyr` also has a `between` helper function that can reduce your conditions to two calls each, but it uses `<=` and `>=`, so you'd need to reconfigure your endpoints.
- You could use `switch`, but all your conditions would need to be in the first term, which will end up looking exactly like the `ifelse` version, and your cases will have nothing to do.
- If your ranges don't overlap, this is better solved with `cut`, which is easy to implement for one variable and could be overwritten by a second.

Comment: Thank you. I also posted a different answer without using ifelse statements. Not sure which one is better.