# Add a variable to this table

Tags: r

[image]

I want to add a variable to the end of this dataset that returns if `shooter_player_id == player_id_off_player` (could be any of players 1 through 5) return player location of corresponding 1-5. I want to find the location of the shooter.  Let me know if there is a better way to show the data than linking the picture.

Comment: Please input your data to ```dput()``` and copy the output from the terminal into your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a new column based on conditional statements and dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003699/how-can-i-create-a-new-column-based-on-conditional-statements-and-dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% mutate(z = case_when(
    shooter_player_id = playerid_off_player_1  ~ AtShot_loc_x_off_player_1 ,
    shooter_player_id = playerid_off_player_2  ~ AtShot_loc_x_off_player_2  ,
    shooter_player_id = playerid_off_player_3  ~ AtShot_loc_x_off_player_3  ,
    shooter_player_id = playerid_off_player_4  ~ AtShot_loc_x_off_player_4 ,
    shooter_player_id = playerid_off_player_5  ~ AtShot_loc_x_off_player_5
  )
)
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly how I did it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome . dplyr package is the best for mutation tasks with conditions.